# Constraint layout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-bottomnavigationview

So I recently moved to constraint layouts, but I can't figure this one out. So here is my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dashboard.DashboardActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dashboard_framelayout"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_dashboard_bottom_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like[image]

So what do I do wrong in my code? I set the constraint of the BottomNavigationView to parent, but somehow it gets pushed further down and I have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does work, but your bottom nav will overlay the FrameLayout.  If that's what you want, then fine.  If you don't want it to overlay, do the following:

In FrameLayout, change `layout_height=0dp` to match constraints.  Also add the following constraint: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/dashboard_bottom_navigation`

In BottomNavigationView you don't have to do anything.  You can leave the top constraint (which will chain the two views) or remove it.  Either way, if you hide the NavView, the FrameLayout will expand to fill the screen and shrink when the NavView is shown.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along and even further, wasnt thinking of that scenario tbh :D thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since FrameLayout is match Parent and you are giving top of bottom navigation to bottom of frame layout and thats why it was going down.

Remove this line

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dashboard_framelayout"
```